# Regular Expression - Linux

Tags: regex, linux, grep

Can we search for a pattern like "\w\w\w\d" which represents three letters followed by a digit in grep ? It is not working. Is there any way on linux terminal to do the same?

for example I would  like to match 'ABC9' or 'NMJ6' etc

Comment: Give us an example of a string that you would like to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -P '\w\w\w\d'
```

Add --color to make it really stand out.
For example:

```
echo 'blahblahABC9blahblah' | grep --color -P '\w\w\w\d'
```

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
echo ABC9 | grep -E '[[:alpha:]]{3}[[:digit:]]' -
```

This makes use of character classes as defined by `man grep`:

```
   Finally,  certain  named  classes  of  characters  are predefined
   within bracket expressions, as follows.   Their  names  are  self
   explanatory,   and  they  are  [:alnum:],  [:alpha:],  [:cntrl:],
   [:digit:], [:graph:], [:lower:], [:print:], [:punct:], [:space:],
   [:upper:],   and  [:xdigit:].   For  example,  [[:alnum:]]  means
   [0-9A-Za-z], except the latter form depends upon the C locale and
   the  ASCII  character encoding, whereas the former is independent
   of locale and character set.  (Note that the  brackets  in  these
   class  names are part of the symbolic names, and must be included
   in addition to the brackets delimiting the  bracket  expression.)
   Most  meta-characters  lose  their special meaning inside bracket
   expressions.  To include a literal ] place it first in the  list.
   Similarly,  to  include  a literal ^ place it anywhere but first.
   Finally, to include a literal - place it last.
```

Answer (score 2):

grep -P "\w\w\w\d"

```
-P, --perl-regexp
Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression.
```